# Caterpillar track odometry model

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, robot, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am now working in a robot which has Caterpillar track instead of normal wheels and i want to make odometry with him. I was hoping that you had some sugestions about how to make a aproximated model.

Thank You

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98186/caterpillar-track-odometry-model/) by [trbf](https://answers.ros.org/users/8366/trbf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer:  You need a gyro to detect turns.    Encoders are not perfect because of the he amount of slippage in turns

Then look at the encoder on each track, use the encoder value from the side that is highest to get distance traveled by that side.  Assume the track in the inside is getting the most slippage.

Or use the gyro to get heading and the average of the two tracks for distance

Also remember that tracked vehicles can go up and down step slopes.  f tracking position in X,Y remember to project the slope onto the plan using cos(slope)

---

Originally posted by [chrisalbertson](https://answers.ros.org/users/21344/chrisalbertson/) with karma: 136 on 2015-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0